# What does `log = True` actually do in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, logarithm

My MCVE:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #normal sample
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

    #histogram
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50)
    plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 800])
    n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(x,50,log=True)
    n1 = np.log(n)
```

now why `n2` is different from `n1`? I thought that the `log = True` scaled everything logarithmically.. but it doesn't. So what is it doing? Same thing happens for `bins2` and `bins1 = np.log(bins)`.

**edit**
This

```
    mu, sigma = 100, 15
    x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(x,50)
    nwidth = bin_edges[7]-bin_edges[6]   #just difference between two random bins
    plt.bar(np.delete(bin_edges,len(bin_edges)-1),hist,nwidth)  #so I have the right number of bins
    plt.show()
```

gives me

[image: a]

then by doing

```
histsq = np.sqrt(np.log(hist))
plt.bar(np.delete(bin_edges,len(bin_edges)-1),histsq,nwidth)
plt.show()
```

I obtain

[image: b]

Comment: I don't think there's any (mathematically valid) way to transform a shape that goes up and then down into a straight line. Do you want to differentiate the histogram?

Comment: @PaulH basically I'm doing all of this because I have some data. I don't know where they come from. But theoretically (at least my lecturer told me so), if I took the log transformation first and then the square root, I should be able to discard or not the option "the data came from a normal distribution". I.e. if I get a straight line, I will know they come from a normal distribution, otherwise I won't know anything.

Comment: then you should be making a probability plot, not a histogram: http://matplotlib.org/mpl-probscale/tutorial/closer_look_at_viz.html#probability-plots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set log = True, the histogram axis (not return parameters) is in log scale. The return parameters (n,bins), ie the values of the bins and the edges of the bins are the same for log = True and log = False. What that means is n==n2 and bins == bins2 are both True.

See the code below to see if that is true

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#normal sample
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

#histogram
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50)
# plt.axis([40, 160, 0, 800])


plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
n2, bins2, patches2 = plt.hist(x,50,log=True)

if (all(n==n2) and all(bins==bins2)):
    print 'Return parameters of hist with log option or without log option are always the same'

#if you want to apply two transformation on the return data and visualize it.
n1 = np.log(n)
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
xx = bins[1:]
yy = np.sqrt(n1)
plt.bar(xx,yy, width = xx[1]-xx[0])

# square root of inverted parabola is not a linear line, but has some curvature

x = np.arange(-1,1.1,.1)
y = 10-(x)**2 # inverted parabola
y1 = np.sqrt(y) # square of inverted parabola

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y, 'b-')
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('inverted parabola', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y1, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sqrt of inverted parabola', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

will return

```
Return parameters of hist method with log option or without log option are always the same
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure I understand what you are saying. If you try with my example, you'll see you get different results!

Comment: Sorry if you cannot understand what i am saying. I edited my answer. basicaly in the plot with log=true, axis will be in log scale and not the return parameters(n, bins). return parameters will be the same with and without log option. hence n==n2 and bins ==bins2.

Comment: okay now it makes sense! Although it makes me have a follow-up question: what does Python actually do when it "scales" the axis? What is the operation that is done?

Comment: @Euler_Salter the simple answer to that last question is: pretty much the same thing as any other plotting library. The more complicated answer involves talking about mapping data coordinates to figure pixels and defining transformations and inverse transformations

Comment: @PaulH because (as you know from my other post) I would like to plot some data in a logarithmic scale (histogram) and then I would like to plot these last data with an extra square root scale! So for example if I had normally distributed data, form the first transformation I would get a parabola and from the second I would get a line. But how on earth can I do that?

Comment: "extra square root scale" makes no sense. First, are you talking about the x- or y-axis?

Comment: @PaulH okay I'll try to be clearer. I have some data, call it $y$. Comes from a normal distribution. I take the logarithm of the data $y$. i.e. $$\log(y) = \log(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}})= \log(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}) - \frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} I.e. I've scaled them with a logarithmic scale. Then I want to scale it with a square root scale, i.e. $$\sqrt(\log(y)) = \sqrt( \log(\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}) - \frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$ So I want to apply $2$ transformations, first the logarithm, then the square root. I should get a straight line

Comment: ffs this stackexchange doesn't even support mathjax

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just take the sqrt of the `counts` array that `numpy.histogram` returns

Comment: @PaulH as counts, you mean the "frequency" that the numpy.histogram returns? That would make sense, but if I only wanted the square root transformation! Instead I want a composition of transformations!

Comment: so do both? `numpy.sqrt(numpy.log10(counts))`

Comment: @PaulH I tried! But the result is not a line! By line I mean that the height of the columns follow a linear pattern. And they don't they are still quadratic-ish. Which means that either I've made some mistake (but there isn't much to do wrong) or this way doesn't work

Comment: @PaulH furthermore, I think it should be logarithm in base $e$, so the natural logarithm. Anyway, I'll post here my code, and you can see that it doesn't work

Comment: So maybe your math is wrong, or the sqrt should be applied to the edges of the bins

Comment: @Euler_Salter I edited my answer to reflect the transformations you are talking about. I use bar method to visulaize such data.

Comment: @user1753919 thank you for doing that. If you try to run it, you will see that the second is a parabola, but the third is not a line! But remember that the samples were taken from a normal distribution, therefore there should be a line

Comment: *"But remember that the samples were taken from a normal distribution, therefore there should be a line"* this is not correct

Comment: @Euler_Salter, please note that we are taking square root of inverted parabola and not a parabola, the square root of inverted parabola is not truly linear but has a curvature. I edited my answer to  show a test case.